# Print contents of memory cells with pointer arithmetics in C

Tags: c, pointers

I would like to access a specific area of memory of a string, and print the contents.

For example, the following piece of code provides the following result:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char *string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
  printf("%.*s", 15, &string[6]); // working
  // printf("%.*s", 15, &string + 6); // not working
  return 0;
}
```

**Output:** `ipsum dolor sit`

Is there a way to achieve the same result by doing pointer arithmetics, that is from the base address sum the offset and print the next `n` contents (in this case 15 characters)?

Apparently doing `printf("%.*s", 15, &string[6]);` in a for cycle with large chunk of text it is very expensive in terms of time, and I was looking at an alternative to it, maybe by accessing directly the contents of a defined memory address (which I'm not sure the example does).

Comment: I think your real problem is that `printf` has to parse the format string and an argument to know what to print. That probably uses much more CPU time than pointer arithmetic. If the length argument is actually a constant, consider creating the format string outside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 3):

`&string[6]` is `&(string[6])`, which is the address of element 6 of `string`.

`&string + 6` is `(&string) + 6`, which is the address of `string` plus six objects beyond that. Pointer arithmetic is performed in units of the pointed-to type. Since `string` is a `char *`, `&string` is a `char **` and points to `char *`. So `&string + 6` attempts to calculate what would be 6 elements beyond `string` in an array of `char *`.

However, `string` is not in an array of `char *`, so this addition is not defined by the C standard. It may produce a pointer to somewhere in the memory of your program, and `printf` may print what it finds there, but that is not behavior you can rely on.

A correct expression for the character six characters beyond the start of `string` would be `string + 6`. This is equivalent to `&string[6]`.

> Apparently doing `printf("%.*s", 15, &string[6]);` in a for cycle with large chunk of text it is very expensive in terms of time,

To write characters with a specific length, you can use `fwrite(source, 1, length, stdout);`, where `source` points to the first character and `length` is the number of characters to write. For example:

```
fwrite(source+6, 1, 15, stdout);
```

(When writing elements of an array other than characters, change `1` to `sizeof *source` to specify the size of each element. Then `length` is the number of elements to write.)

Comment: One difference between `printf("%.*s", 15, string + 6)` and `fwrite(string + 6, 1, 15, stdout)` is safety. Part of what the extra cost of printf buys you is correctly stopping if it reaches the end of the string. To achieve that, you'd need something like `fwrite(string + 6, 1, strnlen(string + 6, 15), stdout)`. Of course neither of those will help is string has fewer than 6 characters.

Answer (score 0):

`string[6]` is syntactic sugar for `*(string + 6)`, so `&string[6]` is exactly equivalent to `&*(string + 6)`. The compiler will cancel out the `&` and `*` for you since they're opposites, which means the operation you're looking for is `(string + 6)`. However, this means that using pointer arithmetic won't be any faster, since it compiles to the exact same code. I'm not really sure what optimization you're trying to do here.